# IF author is author of Post then do something?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to write some simple code to figure out if the user is the author of any posts (Not if their role is author)

My attempt is as follows but I can't figure it out

- I got the userID (set it to current in global header)
- I have created a query to for custom-post-type and author
- I have got all the current posts from the query
- I have added an IF statement (Which I CANT seem to get right)

Here is my code try

```
<?php
// Global variable for current user ID
$user_ID;

// Create a new WP query object           
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'farmers',
'author' => $user_ID
));

// Get all the current user posts from the query object
$posts = $my_query->posts;

IF There are Posts (Not sure how to write this line) {
// Do something
} else {
// Do Something else
} ?>
```

Thanks for any help guidance

Comment: Do you want to check if there are any posts in the WP_Query variable? Do you want to check if in the posts there are any of the current user? Can you expand a little more?

Comment: I want to check if the current Author has been assigned any posts.

Comment: just to note I am not good at PHP, but if you mean what it looks like when I echo it, I get returned "Array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
if( $posts ) {
  // Do something
} 
else {
  // Do Something else
}
```